# How to make the left hand side of an image clickable while the image is responsive?

Tags: html, css

How to I make 50% of an image clickable while maintaining the image responsiveness?

I have tried using the area tag and various other methods which have been discussed in other questions but none of them are responsive.

The website I am doing this on is [spectrospective.com.au](http://spectrospective.com.au/) and it is the main Spectrospective banner image which says 'play film' and 'play trailer'.

The div I am targetting is:

```
<div class="hero-video">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myhome">
            <img src="images/homepage-banner.png" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could try to position a div over you image, divide it into two and give the two children different links accordingly.

Comment: have you tried making the img outside the `a` and the `a` positioned absolute with 50% width ?

Comment: Just two `a` links in the container, positionned `absolute` z-index 2 and `50%` width, one `top left` the other `top right`. Your image should not be in the `a` but directly in the `.container` and positionned absolute z-index 1, top 0 right 0 bottom 0 left 0 (mean 100% width and height of your container)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `position: absolute` to hover it over half of your image (see working example). Hope this helps.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 5em;
  height:10em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="image.png" />
  <a href="alink.html"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this helped allot and now I understand positioning better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I probably would've commented this, but I don't have 50 rep yet... soo anyway, why not get the image, cut it in half in an image editor (Photoshop, GIMP, etc) and then put the images side by side with a different `<a href>`.

ALTERNATE SOLUTION: create a clear div that covers half of the image and change the `<a href>` to whatever you want it to be.